# Leaflet Marker with button inside

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm adding a bunch of markers on my map the following way:

```
L.marker({ lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude }, { icon: myIcon })
  .bindPopup("<h1>" + this.name + "</h1><p>" + this.desc +
  "</p><button (click)=\"showMore(" + this.id +
  ")\">Show more</button>")
```

But It seems the HTML code isn't compiled by Angular.

How can I achieve this using Ionic 2 since $compile doesn't exist anymore ?